# locate element using lxml.html vs BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm scraping an html document using `lxml.html`; there's one thing I can do in `BeautifulSoup`, but don't manage to do with lxml.htm. Here it  is:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

doc = ['<html>',
'<h2> some text </h2>',
'<p> some more text </p>',
'<table> <tr> <td> A table</td> </tr> </table>',
'<h2> some special text </h2>',
'<p> some more text </p>',
'<table> <tr> <td> The table I want </td> </tr> </table>',
'</html>']
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(doc))
print soup.find(text=re.compile("special")).findNext('table')
```

I tried this with `cssselect`, but no success. Any ideas on how I could locate this using the methods in `lxml.html`?

Many thanks,
D

Comment: Why do you need the `re.compile` on the constant string `"special"`?

Comment: Also, personally I've always found `BeautifulSoup` more convenient for HTML "scraping" than `lxml`

Comment: Hi @Eli, thanks for your comment. I was also not sure why I need `re.compile' here, but the fact is that `print soup.find(text="special").findNext('table')' doesn't work. Also, it seems that `BeautifulSoup' is not maintained any more, see http://tiny.cc/d1lir.

Comment: that link isn't providing up-to-date information - see the comment I added to that answer

Comment: One time, I compared the execution's times of regex,lxml and BeautifulSoup for one problem. I observed lxml being 100 times slower than regex, and BeautifulSoup 1000 slower than regex. I don't know if this result is general or particular to the 3 codes I tested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression in an lxml Xpath, by using [EXSLT syntax](http://exslt.org/regexp/functions/test/index.html).  For example, given your document, this will select the parent node whose text matches the regexp `spe.*al`:

```
import re
import lxml.html

NS = 'http://exslt.org/regular-expressions'
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(DOC)

# select sibling table nodes after matching node
path = "//*[re:test(text(), 'spe.*al')]/following-sibling::table"
print tree.xpath(path, namespaces={'re': NS})

# select all sibling nodes after matching node
path = "//*[re:test(text(), 'spe.*al')]/following-sibling::*"
print tree.xpath(path, namespaces={'re': NS})
```

Output:

```
[<Element table at 7fe21acd3f58>]
[<Element p at 7f76ac2c3f58>, <Element table at 7f76ac2e6050>]
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm looking for is not the parent node of the matched text (h2 here); it's (in this example, a sibling, but more generally) an element following that node.

Comment: You should be able to use [xpath axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp) to select exactly what you're looking for. I've updated to select the `table` node, but you can generalize the path however you need.

Comment: samplebias gives a good answer here. xpath is extremely powerful; much more powerful than the tools BS gives (although you can use the BS parser in lxml). BS shines with extremely broken HTML, but for ordinary cases lxml is hands-down the more flexible (with downside of largish binary dependency).